# How can I get the ID of a character inside an object

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I have an array of movies and inside each movie is another array for characters. When I click on a character I'd like to show various bits of information about them (name, age, etc.) and in order to do that, I need the `id` of each character.

```
const PopularBooks = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Harry Potter",
    characters: [
      {
        id: 10,
        name: "Harry Potter",
      },
      {
        id: 11,
        name: "Hermione",
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        name: "Ron",
      },
    ],
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Lord of the Rings",
    characters: [
      {
        id: 13,
        name: "Frodo",
      },
      {
        id: 14,
        name: "Legolas",
      },
      {
        id: 15,
        name: "Gandalf",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Inside the main book page I have each character displayed inside an image and when you click on the character it sends you to another web page where the params is the characters id.

```
        <% book.characters.forEach(character => { %>
          <div class="portrait">
            <a href="/character/<%= character.id %>">
              <img
                src="/images/characters/book-c-<%= character.id %>.png"
              />
            </a>
            <p><%= character.name %></p>
          </div>
          <% }); %>
```

I have set the params in my router function to a characterId function which works fine, however when I try sorting through my data array again to compare the `characterId` function to the characters actual `id`, the character id is returning as undefined and I'm left with this error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')`

```
const data = require("../data");

router.get("/character/:character", function (req, res, next) {
  const characterId = parseInt(req.params.character);
  const character = data.PopularBooks.characters.find(
    (characters) => characters.id === characterId
  );
  console.log(characterId);
  console.log(character);
  res.render("character", { character });
});
```

I need this information to set up a page for each unique character. What am I doing wrong to cause this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the characters array of a specific book, but you are currently searching for the character within the entire *PopularBooks* array. You need to first find the correct book by its ID and then search for the character:

```
...
//find the book containing the character
const bookWithCharacter = data.PopularBooks.find((book) =>
  book.characters.some((character) => character.id === characterId)
);

if (!bookWithCharacter) {
  //if ID is not found in any book
  return res.status(404).send("Character not found");
}

//find the specific character within the book
const character = bookWithCharacter.characters.find(
  (char) => char.id === characterId
);
....
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue arises from how you access characters in PopularBooks. Since each book has its characters and PopularBooks is a book array, you must search books to find the right character by characterId. Your current method, directly using data.PopularBooks.characters, will not work as characters belong to individual books, not PopularBooks.

```
 const data = require("../data");

router.get("/character/:character", function (req, res, next) {
  const characterId = parseInt(req.params.character);
  
  let foundCharacter = null;
  for (const book of data.PopularBooks) {
    foundCharacter = book.characters.find(character => character.id === characterId);
    if (foundCharacter) {
      break; 
    }
  }
  
  console.log(characterId);
  console.log(foundCharacter);
  
  res.render("character", { character: foundCharacter });
});
```